# C++: Makefile: object files not compiling? make then says objects not found

Tags: c++, makefile

So, client.o and server.o are not being compiled... but the make file doesn't error...

I've checked the directory where all the code is and the sub folders. but client and server .o just aren't there... =\

here is my make file:

```
main_objects = src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/Config.o

network_objects = src/neural_network_basic.o
hash_objects = src/hashes.o src/hashes/Murmur.o 
cloud_objects = src/cloud/client.o src/cloud/server.o

all_objects = $(main_objects) $(hash_objects) $(network_objects) $(cloud_objects)

all: hPif clean

hPif : $(all_objects)
    g++ -o hPif $(all_objects) -lfann -L/usr/local/lib 

src/cloud/client.o : src/cloud/chat_client.cpp src/cloud/chat_message.hpp
    g++ -c src/cloud/chat_client.cpp 

src/cloud/server.o : src/cloud/chat_server.cpp src/cloud/chat_message.hpp src/cloud/chat_server.h
    g++ -c src/cloud/chat_server.cpp 

neural_network_basic.o : src/neural_network_basic.cpp src/neural_network_basic.h
    g++ -c src/neural_network_basic.cpp

hashes/Murmur.o : src/hashes/Murmur.cpp src/hashes/Murmur.h
    g++ -c src/hashes/Murmur.cpp

Config.o : src/Config.cpp src/Config.h
    g++ -c src/Config.cpp

hashes.o : src/hashes.cpp src/hashes.h
    g++ -c src/hashes.cpp

fann_utils.o: src/fann_utils.cpp fann_utils.h
    g++ -c src/fann_utils.cpp 

main.o: src/main.cpp src/main.h 
    g++ -c src/main.cpp

clean: 
    rm -rf src/cloud/*.o
    rm -rf src/hashes/*.o
    rm -rf src/*.o
    rm -rf *.o
```

Console output looks like this:

```
g++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++    -c -o src/fann_utils.o src/fann_utils.cpp
g++    -c -o src/Config.o src/Config.cpp
g++    -c -o src/hashes.o src/hashes.cpp
g++    -c -o src/hashes/Murmur.o src/hashes/Murmur.cpp
g++    -c -o src/neural_network_basic.o src/neural_network_basic.cpp
g++ -c src/cloud/chat_client.cpp 
g++ -c src/cloud/chat_server.cpp 
g++ -o hPif src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/Config.o src/hashes.o src/hashes/Murmur.o  src/neural_network_basic.o src/cloud/client.o src/cloud/server.o -lfann -L/usr/local/lib 
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: src/cloud/client.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: src/cloud/server.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [hPif] Error 1
```

Comment: 1) remove all rules that are irrelevant to the problem (e.g. `neural_network_basic.o`), 2) try `make src/cloud/client.o`, 3) tell us what happens.

Comment: I typed make src/cloud/client.o
 into the terminal... it gave the corresponding output that is in my post. Still no file. =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g++ -c src/cloud/chat_client.cpp` will build an object file called `chat_client.o`, not `client.o`. Either add `-o $@` to the rule to create an object file with the same name as the target, or rename the file to `chat_client.o` everywhere it's mentioned in the makefile.

Comment: chat_client.o doesn't exist either... =\

Comment: @DerNalia: that's because the other targets don't depend on it, and there's no rule to build it - they depend on `client.o`, which is the target of the rule (but not built by the rule).